# Searching for Runs of Consecutive Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am working on a simple scheduler for a computer server and need to take this array:

```
Array 
( 
   [Mon] => false, 
   [Tues] => true, 
   [Wed] => false,
   [Thurs] => true, 
   [Fri] => true,
   [Sat] => true,
   [Sun] => false
)
```

And get an array returned like this:

```
Array
(
   'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'
)
```

Basically, I am looking for instances where the array has `True` more than twice in a row. It could be Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, it could be Friday, Saturday, Sunday, but it could not be Monday, Wednesday, Thursday.

My first thought was to come up with every possibility and hard-code that as an array, then `foreach` through each possibility, but it took much too long and felt sloppy.

Thanks

Comment: What output are you looking for if, say, all days are true except Thursday?

Answer (score 2):

This will return the first sequence of 3, or an empty array if no such sequence exists:

```
function getDays(array $schedule) {

    $sequence = array();

    foreach($schedule as $day => $value) {
        if($value) {
            $sequence[] = $day;

            // check if we have enough trues to exit
            if(count($sequence) > 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // we found a false, so reset any existing sequence
            $sequence = array();
        }
    }

    return $sequence;
}

$schedule = array( 
       'Mon' => false, 
       'Tues' => true, 
       'Wed' => false,
       'Thurs' => true, 
       'Fri' => true,
       'Sat' => true,
       'Sun' => false
    );

print_r(getDays($schedule));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thurs
    [1] => Fri
    [2] => Sat
)
```

Comment: You're changing the OP's array. I think they're strings, not boolean values.

Comment: Indeed they are; I hadn't noticed. Because it is a trivial change rather than an incorrect solution, and booleans make more sense in this context, I shall leave it as is. Not convinced it deserves a downvote..

Comment: This is the better solution, but not quite what the OP asked for. Yeah, I've removed the downvote now. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$daysTest = array(
     '0-Thurs,Fri,Sat' => array('Mon' => false, 'Tues' => true,'Wed' => false, 'Thurs' => true,'Fri' => true, 'Sat' => true,'Sun' => false)
    ,'1-Thurs,Fri,Sat' => array('Mon' => true,  'Tues' => true,'Wed' => false, 'Thurs' => true,'Fri' => true, 'Sat' => true,'Sun' => false)
    ,'2-Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,Sun' => array('Mon' => true, 'Tues' => true,'Wed' => true, 'Thurs' => true,'Fri' => true, 'Sat' => true,'Sun' => false)
    ,'3-' => array('Mon' => false, 'Tues' => true,'Wed' => false, 'Thurs' => true,'Fri' => false, 'Sat' => true,'Sun' => true)

);
$minLength = 3;
foreach ($daysTest as $target => $days) {

$result = array();
$stack  = array();
foreach ($days as $key => $match) {
    if ( $match ) {
        $stack[] = $key;
    }
    else {
        if ( $minLength <= count($stack)) {
            $result += $stack;
        }
        $stack  = array();
    }
}
if ( $minLength <= count($stack)) {
    $result += $stack;
}
echo 'Result:',implode(',',$result),"\n";
echo 'Target:',$target,"\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for any number of days

```
$days = array('Mon' => 'false', 'Tues' => 'true', 
              'Wed' => 'false', 'Thurs' => 'true', 
              'Fri' => 'true', 'Sat' => 'true', 
              'Sun' => 'false');

while ($day = array_shift($days)) {
        if($day == next($days)) {
            $result[] = array_search($day, $days)."<br/>";
        }
} 
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Wed

    [1] => Thurs

    [2] => Fri

)
```

[**See it in action!**](http://codepad.org/dr1cFtWh)

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 7

Comment: It's completely wrong using string!! false for boolean value, if you take  the original input array which uses real booleans, your code breaks http://codepad.org/CNZeO08K

Comment: @cske: See the OP's array. It uses strings, not boolean values. I worked with what was given in the question.

Comment: @Amal Murali: confusing and bad style anyway (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php (string)false is not considered FALSE), and no need for array_search also, simple key($days) do the trick